# How to write multiple nested objects in a C# model to a SQL database

Tags: sql, c#-4.0, webapi

I have the following model object in C# that I'm receiving in a WEB API from a POST - Does anyone know how I would write this object to a database? The tables can be whatever, I'm just not sure how to cycle through this model to get the 'Sequence', 'Quote' and 'Items' to flat files from objects.

```
public class PickupDetail
{   public string driver_name;

    public class PickupDate  
    {   
        public DateTime pickup_date;
        
        public class Sequence
        {   ...Sequence fields

            public class Quote
            {   ...Quote fields

                public class Item
                {   ....Item fields

                    public class OriginalItem
                    {
                        ...OriginalItem fields
                    }
                    public OriginalItem original;
                }
                public List<Item> items;
            }
            public List<Quote> quotes;
        }
        public List<Sequence> sequence;
    }
    public List<PickupDate> dates;
}
```

Comment: This question could be improved by removing some of the fields in your example classes. To see the nested `List<...>` member variables, which form the basis of the questions, the reader needs to scroll down.

Comment: Sure. I went ahead and removed all of the field names from the classes for brevity.

Comment: Were you able to try out a solution based on nhibernate?

Answer (score 0):

From information you are giving it is not obvious what would be the usage for the software you have but given that data I suggest you learn more about [ORMs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) such as [nHibernate](http://nhibernate.info/).
Then configure your models using [Fluent nHibernate](http://www.fluentnhibernate.org/). Then only thing you need to do is
_session.SaveOrUpdate(pickupDetail);

The ORM will take care of creation and/or updating of the nested properties.

Comment: The usage for this is a shipping logistics company, so a pickup date will have multiple quotes which will have multiple items, which is why there are nested classes.